# How to password protect a Docker image or a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3333

CMD npm start
```

I just started out Docker and with this Dockerfile I can then build an image and use it in a container. Basic.

I want to add some securities in it. Maybe not letting any user do something like `docker container exec -it my_container bash` without entering a password?

Is there a way to require any user to enter a root password when doing `docker container exec -it my_container bash`? I want to protect the files inside it. Or maybe just require a password when creating a container with that image.

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command can freely `docker exec` without restrictions, `docker run` alternate commands to get debugging shells on the image, and generally has unrestricted root access to the host system and can look at any file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make one user id and put the line about login as that user?

try

```
RUN useradd --system --create-home --shell /bin/bash --password password username
RUN login username
```

So you can put the password as you want.

Comment: Will this restrict any user from running docker container exec?

Comment: This is not working. Retuned the error `The command '/bin/sh -c login username' returned a non-zero code: 1`